# Asp.Net Localization : How to process XML data file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, localization

Based on the article [aspnet-mvc-internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx), I have created a separate resource file for each locale. I can process all the views and built in code. But how should I process data specified in XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
<item Text="@Resources.Home" NavigateUrl="~/Home">
<item Text="@Resources.Dashboard" NavigateUrl="~/Routing/Dashboard"/>
</item>

</items>
```

The @Resources.Home doesn't work. This is somewhere similar to sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

I came out with a solution to have a xml file for each locale. And then bind the path with a locale helper class.

```
    public static string GetPath()
    {
        var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        string letters = culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(letters))
            return String.Empty;
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/App_Data/TopMenu.{0}.xml", letters));

    }
```

E.g. TopMenu.en.xml, TopMenu.es.xml

.BindToXML(CultureHelper.GetPath(), "/items/*").GetHtml()